# Google Maps Activity crashes when zooming in/out too fast with strange error

Tags: java, android-studio, runtime-error

So I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HD48FBwY9U0) set of tutorials on how to work around the Google Maps Activity.

It's going well, however, when I open the activity and zoom in/out too fast, the app crashes and closes.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0
string: 'Having fun in the studio this morning  (1).mp4'
in call to NewStringUTF
from java.lang.String[] java.io.File.listImpl(java.lang.String)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
| group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x74de11d0 self=0xb4827800
| sysTid=5975 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6fc7bec
| state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=386 stm=84 core=3 HZ=100
| stack=0xbe6c1000-0xbe6c3000 stackSize=8MB
| held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

And many more lines down relating the error.

I'm confused here, because I know what causes errors like `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0`.

What I don't understand is where the string `"Having fun in the studio this morning  (1).mp4"` came from. Because clearly, the emoji is what's causing the issue. Yet this string is nowhere in my code, and seems to cause problems when the map is being zoomed in/out too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is not related to your application. As information is very limited in your question so below are some questions which will help you to find the root cause of this issue:

1. Is this issue happening on all devices or only on one device?

   > My guess is, it is device specific issue
2. Is this issue 100% reproducible?
3. Is there some pattern to reproduce the issue or randomly reproducing?

As I mentioned issue looks device specific you can **factory reset** device and test again.

Comment: It only happens when running the app on my Samsung Galaxy J3 running Lollipop 5.1.1... works fine on other android versions.